# Azure AD / Python AA

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a quite simple usecase. From my product I have to implement some kind of authentication / authorization backend for my custom application. The application itself supports LDAP as AA backend (w/o kerberos), but I'm not sure if Azure AD can be used this way externally. Is this possible?

If not, I'm going to implement some authentication / authorization using standard python libraries. I've already found a lots of resources on this, however the whole picture still quite foggy. Basically I need two functions, authenticate the user (by evaluating the username/password received by the python script), and also check some kind of group membership for authorization as I would do in LDAP.

I don't want to invent the hot water, so, if there is any snippet for this, it would be great

Thank you
L:

Comment: [Here's a sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-flask-graphapi-web-v2) for using AzureAD w/ Python (flask framework).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Azure AD for that, you would want to work against [Azure Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx)

High level steps:

1. [Create Azure AD Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication#a-nameexpress-aconfigure-azure-active-directory-using-express-settings)
2. [Figure out token auth](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python)
3. And using the REST API link figure the API calls to find appropriate permissions (probably adal can do that, not sure)